# "$x == $y" is true in PHP when $x and $y are "not equal"?

Tags: php, if-statement, equals-operator

I've been a developer for decades - in many programming languages. I can't get a very simple straight forward "if" statement to work in PHP:

```
if($groupminc == $groupmaxc)

    {
     echo "AFTER1:GROUPMIN==>" . $groupminc . "\n";
     echo "AFTER1:GROUPMAX==>" .  $groupmaxc . "\n";
     $groupmsg = $groupminc . " Participant";
    }
  else
   {
     echo "AFTER2:GROUPMIN==>" . $groupminc . "\n";
     echo "AFTER2:GROUPMAX==>" .  $groupmaxc . "\n";
     $groupmsg = $groupminc . " to " . $groupmaxc . " Participants";
   }
```

I'm getting the AFTER1 happening even when $groupminc and $groupmaxc are clearly **not equal.**

Comment: try to debug $groupminc and $groupmaxc before if statement

Comment: What are the values of $groupminc and $groupmaxc?

Comment: PHP is losely typed... if you want to compare type as well as value then use the `===` operator otherwise things will be dynamically cast to "what makes sense as far as i can tell"...

Comment: Post the result you get from `echo`. Or use `var_dump($groupminc);`

Comment: Before trying anything it is better if you clarify the types of `$groupminc` and `$groupmaxc`. Otherwise you will get a half-assed answer and you will definitely will be back later.

Comment: For being an experienced developer, it should be practice to consult the fine manual ... e.g. [the section on `==`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). Also, trying things out on a REPL (or "codepad") can help decrease the time it takes to absorb different rules/heuristics/concepts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do the equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparis)

Answer (score 2):

try with `===` :

```
if($groupminc === $groupmaxc)
```

Comment: If they are **clearly not equal** then I guess that means that they're content isn't equal, not just their type. This probably won't help at all.

Comment: @Simon: id put money on this actually being the issue/solution *clearly not equal* is a subjective phrase... to someone used to other languages `String(0)` may be clearly not equal to `Integer(0)`

Comment: @prodigitalson I am starting to think that you are right, I just realized (after getting a bug on my own) that a non-empty string (excluding some special ones) compared to the integer 1 equals true. That could very well be the case here. Because after all, the string "bug" is "clearly not equal" (according to even myself) to the integer 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're finding here is the difference between the `==` and the `===` operators. There's a pretty good answer at [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparis)

Answer (score 0):

Show us your complete code with the initialization of the variables.

Or just try following:

```
echo ($groupminc !== $groupmaxc ? $groupminc.' to ' : '').$groupmaxc.' Participants';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more clear, what values you get in $groupminc and $groupmaxc.Otherwise there may be issue of `==` and `===`